# Cache Versioning on Progressive Web Apps

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

What is the current best practice for service worker caching?

After using service workers and caching for a number of projects, we are having a bit of a maintenance headache to manage the cached assets for the project.

In most cases we are using a static cache (most likely the cause of our headache) and our sw.js code is pretty standard and looks as follows:

```
var cacheName = 'v1:static';

// cache static assets during install phase
self.addEventListener('install', function (e) {
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function (cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                './',
                './css/style.css',
                './css/vendor.css',
                './js/build/script.min.js',
                './js/build/vendor.min.js'
            ]).then(function () {
                self.skipWaiting();
            });
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {        
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                // retrieve from cache
                return response;
            }
            // fetch as normal
            return fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});
```

The problems begin once we release a new version of our app and we need to invalidate the cache for the user.

What methods are recommended to update the cache? I am aware of [sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache) or developers who manually update the cacheName variable (or perhaps through a task-runner). Are there other alternatives? Is there a way to only invalidate one file instead of the entire cache?

Thanks

Comment: It's not uncommon to see scripts loaded via `/path/to/script.js?v=1.2.3` and that v parameter being linked to a project version number. If your cache will eventually expire (which it should) then you don't need to bother with removing old entries.

Comment: You mention being aware of `sw-precache`, and it's intended for the use case you're describing. Is there a reason why you'd rather not use it? (I'm the author, and am curious as to whether there are downsides you're worried about.)

Comment: @JeffPosnick I think it serves its purpose well (and allows you to implement precaching without knowing what goes on under-the-hood); but since service workers are relatively new I personally prefer to write most of the bootstrapping code for now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you do an assets assessment of your project(s).  Determine the static assets from the dynamic ones.  Once you have determined the pure static ones, precache it.

There are 2 ways of doing this.  1) use [sw-toolbox](https://googlechrome.github.io/sw-toolbox/) or 2) manually update the version number of the service worker file for the browser to update it.

I know the pain that you are experiencing with invalidating the cache and everything.  You might want to try/implement [sw-toolbox](https://googlechrome.github.io/sw-toolbox/).

**sw-toolbox method**

```
const OFFLINE_URL = '/pages/offline/';

importScripts('sw-toolbox.js');

self.toolbox.precache([
    <PATH_TO_STATIC_ASSET>
    'manifest.json',
    OFFLINE_URL,
    '/'
]);

self.toolbox.router.default = self.toolbox.networkFirst;

self.toolbox.router.get('/(.*)', function (req, vals, opts) {
    return self.toolbox.networkFirst(req, vals, opts)
        .catch(function (error) {
            if (req.method === 'GET' && req.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html')) {
                return self.toolbox.cacheOnly(new Request(OFFLINE_URL), vals, opts);
            }
            throw error;
        });
    });
```

**Google Service Worker Boilerplate** - [link](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/service-worker/prefetch/service-worker.js)

This one too is pretty straight forward.  The only down side of this is that at every deployment, you have to update the `CACHE_VERSION` for the service-worker installed to update automatically.

Take note also that there is [Workbox](https://workboxjs.org/) also.  I havent played around with it that much yet so my methods could be outdated.  They say that this is the descendant to precache and toolbox

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way it is if you update the CACHE_NAME in your service workers JS file so it will be installed again.